# use multiple parameters to an imap fetch request

Tags: command, imap, fetch

I want the command syntaxe for imap to get juste header et text body from a message without attachments.

I have try this command but don't work : 
UID FETCH uid (BODY[HEADER] BODY[1])

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What is the error?  ``BODY[1]`` isn't necessarily the text body, depending on the formatting of the message.  You would need to get the BODYSTRUCTURE and interpret that.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a raw fetch command to fetch mail data

```
UID FETCH 2 (BODY[]<0.size>)
```

for example if you want to fetch first 100 bytes of mail then you can fire a command as

```
UID FETCH 2 (BODY[]<0.100>)
```

but then you will have to parse the data yourself.